# Command works when button is clicked, but not when keybinding is used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I click the MenuItem the command works fine, but when I hit the key binding for it never get called. Any ideas?

XAML:

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="N"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{Binding Path=MenuCommands:NewProject}"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
<MenuItem x:Name="NewProjectMenuItem"
                      Header="New Project"
                      Click="NewProjectMenuItem_Click"
                      InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
```

C# (XAML source):

```
private void NewProjectMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuCommands.NewProject.Execute(NewProjectMenuItem);
    }
```

NOTE: I am binding to the input in a page, I can't bind it in the window without doing some major changes to the program.

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, InputGestureText is not a real binding. It's just a visual hint. You must code the keybinding in the Window_PreviewKeyDown.

KeyBinding can be catched by some control, so it's better to avoid it.

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.N:
                MenuCommands.NewProject.Execute(NewProjectMenuItem);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CaptainPicard Put that answer as validated in order to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the CanExecute event to true.

XAML:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="B"
          Modifiers="Control" 
          Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" CanExecute="CommonCommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="OpenCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>


<Button Command="Open" ToolTip="Open">
    <Image Source="/WPFeBookProject;component/Resources/Images/Open-icon.png" />
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void CommonCommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void OpenCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Open executed has been triggered!");
}
```